# How to remove a selected option from all other dropdown fields?

Tags: javascript, ejs

I have 4 dropdown fields, all of them display the same data dynamically. If one option is selected it shall be removed as a option from the other dropdown fields. How can I achieve this using JS?

```
 <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="winner1">
                    <% nameArray.forEach(function(item){ %>
                        <option> <%= item.name %> </option>
                    <% }) %>
</select>

 <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="winner2">
                    <% nameArray.forEach(function(item){ %>
                        <option> <%= item.name %> </option>
                    <% }) %>
</select>

<select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="looser1">
                <% nameArray.forEach(function(item){ %>
                    <option> <%= item.name %> </option>
                <% }) %>
</select>

<select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="looser2">
                    <% nameArray.forEach(function(item){ %>
                        <option> <%= item.name %> </option>
                    <% }) %>
    </select>
```

Comment: JavaScript is **not** Java... I updated the question tags.

Comment: We also need to see what you've tried (your javascript code).